# How to use Orchard.Scripting?

Tags: c#, orchardcms

Now, I'm working with Orchard CMS.
I need to change some fields on around 50 content items on one Orchard instance.
I'd like to do this without deploying new code to all current and future Orchard instances.
and the Project Manager said "Orchard.Scripting looks appropriate for this use case".

But... i don't know what is Orchard.Scripting and how to use it.
I try to looking at [Orchard-Scripting-Extensions](https://github.com/Lombiq/Orchard-Scripting-Extensions/) and [Orchard-Scripting-Extensions-DotNet](https://github.com/Lombiq/Orchard-Scripting-Extensions-DotNet/) for document and example.
not found what i'm looking.

Can anyone tell me how to use it.
Thank you !!!

Comment: I don't think Orchard.Scripting is what you're looking for, no: what it does is provide some infrastructure for modules to accept bits of code as part of their inputs. It's not a general purpose way to script Orchard. It does look like something interesting could be built along those lines however. We do have a command-line interface that may be worth checking out, and might work for you, and/or import recipes. Recipes are a good way to make bulk changes on content items, and the format is relatively easy to generate.